# Maven Shade assemble order

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

When I use Maven Shade to build my assembly jar, some properties files will be replaced if they have the same file name, for example, "logback.xml". I have my own logback.xml in my project, however, it exists in other 3rd jars, too.

How can it be configured to use project's properties files in prior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try filtering out files that you dont want to be included. See [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-shade-plugin-1.4/examples/includes-excludes.html).